# runOnUiThread not working consistently

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I'm working with `Thread` in order to update the UI.
I have a basic registration form which asks for *State* and *Country* when entering address. I display those 2 values on final screen having summary.

Now, there is a `Edit` button to edit the info where I want to retrieve the *State* and *Country* value in respective fields and hence I'm using below method.

But its working inconsistently i.e. some time both gets populated, sometimes one of them, sometimes none of them.

PLEASE NOTE I'm using `ViewFlipper` in my app(I don't know if it has anything to do).

I'm banging my head from a day on it, but haven't find any solution/ suggestion for the same.

Any help appreciated.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    setState.setText(dispState.getText());
                                    setCountry.setText(dispCoun.getText());
                                }
                            });
                            constants.threadCount =0;
                            try {
                                if (constants.threadCount == 0)
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                    constants.threadCount = 1;
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
```

### Edit

```
edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// DO SOMETHING
// Starting Thread
vf.setDisplayedChild(9);
}
});
```

Comment: Can you include where you execute the thread?

Comment: seems to me like you are trying to block the main thread...

Comment: @Ramyle : I'm starting this thread on click event of button

Comment: you are running on the UI thread `while(true)`, this blocks the UI thread always

Comment: what do you suggest then? I want Thread to run only once. So the condition I've written in `try-catch` should be used instead of `while(true)`?

Comment: You can `setText()` without a thread.

Comment: @Ramyle : I tried that only, But since it din't worked, I used `Thread`.

Comment: Use handler instead of using runOnUIThread()

Comment: @pvn : can u suggest the example code snippet...

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to acheive, but a TextWatcher would pronbably be more efficient, as it looks like you are trying to detect texts changes

Comment: @njzk2  : after filling all info, user wants to edit info and hence comes to edit page. On edit page I'm not getting State and Country values which used has entered consistently even though I've written code for that(which is present in `run()` method).

Comment: When you say screen, do you mean Fragment or Activity?

Comment: I'm using `ViewFlipper` within a single `Activity` which has several `Views` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
constants.threadCount = 0;
                final Handler handler=new Handler();
                final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        if (constants.threadCount <4) {
                            setState.setText(dispState.getText());
                            setCountry.setText(dispCoun.getText());

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                        constants.threadCount++;
                        }
                    }
                };

                Thread threadnew = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (constants.threadCount <4) {
                                sleep(1000);
                                handler.post(r);
                                constants.threadCount++;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                threadnew.start();
```